# CSS class under an ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to target multiple elements and classes under a specific ID. NOTE: I must specify the ID. The classes will be used again with other IDs

```
#block-views-now-playing2-block .poster1 img
{
   width:auto;
   height:400px;    
}

#block-views-now-playing2-block .poster1 div
{
   width:263px;
   height:400px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

In this example the img element accepts the css. The div does not and the CSS is ignored. Why?

HTML:

```
<div class="block block-views contextual-links-region last even" id="block-views-now-playing2-block">
   <div class="field-content poster1">
      <img src="http://mysite/myposter.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Without that, there is no way we can answer this question.

Comment: Does the div have the class `poster1`? If so, your css needs to be `#block-views-now-playing2-block div.poster1` or just `#block-views-now-playing2-block .poster1`

Comment: Let me see your HTML.  Some elements cannot be wrapped in themselves

Comment: What nickspiel said did it! Im going to have to brush up on why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an ID in front to your CSS selector will not affect, *how* things are selected, but rather *where*. When you start with `#block-views-now-playing2-block` you are limiting the scope of what you're looking for to anything contained inside of `#block-views-now-playing2-block`

So `#block-views-now-playing2-block .poster1 img` reads: "Find any `img` that exists inside of and element with class `poster1` which exists inside of an element with the ID `block-views-now-playing2-block`".

It works the same way for you `div` example.

For the CSS to find something the html would need to be structured something like this:

```
<div id="block-views-now-playing2-block">
  <div class="poster1">
    <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you were to change the CSS to `#block-views-now-playing2-block.poster1 img` (notice the missing space). The CSS would read: "Any `img` inside of an element that has an ID of `block-views-now-playing2-block.poster1` and a class of `poster1`"  The css now would only find something if the HTML were structured similar to:

```
<div id="block-views-now-playing2-block" class="poster1">
  <div>
    <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Notice the class moved up one level with the ID)

But really I can only guess why it isn't working for you without seeing your HTML.